# Changing Google's OAuth 2.0 approved redirect URLs programmatically

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api

My product, which uses Google calendar, has many different customers that each have their own domain, which requires me to list each domain in the approved redirect URLs field in the OAuth settings.  Is there a way to edit this field thru the API, or is it only editable by the admin thru the website?